# Deleting vowels in a string. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, arrays, string, logical-operators

I am trying to delete all the vowels of a string by putting all the consonants into a different array and then re-initializing the first array to the second one. After that the first array is supposed to be printed, that is, only the consonants. I'm really not sure where the problem lies, I've been looking at this problem for a good three hours, and I'm so tired of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str [100];
    char garbage[100];
    int loopcondition = 0 , j = 0 , k = 0;
    int userinput;
    char a = "a" , e = "e" , i = "i", o = "o" , u = "u";

    printf("!!!Hello World!!! Please type in a string from which I can  remove all the vowels:\n");

    //This program is supposed to take in a string and then delete all the vowels

    gets(str); //gets user input

    userinput = strlen(str); //makes userinput equal to the length of the string

    while(loopcondition < userinput) //the loop runs until the condition is no longer smaller than the input
    {
        loopcondition++;    //incrementation of condition
        if(str[j] != a || e || i || o || u) // this should check wether the current position in the array is a vowel
        {
            garbage[k] = str[j] ; //if it's not the it puts the current character into the garbage array
            k++;        //iteration of the garbage array position
        };
        j++; //incrementation of string array position
    };

    garbage[k] = '\0';
    strcpy (str , garbage ); //this copies the string?!?! aka reinitiliazing array variable
    printf("%s" , str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: warning: never use `gets()`, use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger! This will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Specify what's the problem. You've provided the code and explained it. Then you say , "I don't know what's the problem". Problem? Elaborate.

Comment: There's a \n missing in the last printf, although it may not be a problem here since it's just before main returns, you should make sure to check them all because it can wait for the next \n to be bufferised before printing what you expect

Comment: @Tamanici , "*are you serious?*" Yes. But I'm not being rude. "*If I knew how to 'specify' the problem I would have not made this post*" -- If did not know about the problem, you wouldn't have posted this. So you know that something is wrong. Specify that in the post. You surely would've seen warnings. Post them here. 
I told to specify the problem as there are a LOT of problems ranging from crashes, compiler-errors and warnings to weird things happening in the program. Specify what's wrong. Is the output wrong? Is the compiler complaining about the code? etc. Sorry if I was rude to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `char` initializations should look like

```
char a = 'a' , e = 'e' , i = 'i', o = 'o' , u = 'u';
```

Remember, the *double-quotes* (`" "`) are meant for *string literals*, the *single quotes* (`''`) are for *character literals*.

Then,

```
  if(str[j] != a || e || i || o || u)
```

this is not how you use logical OR (`||`) operators in c. Chaining is not possible. You have to check each condition separately. Something like

```
if( (str[j] != a) && 
                     (str[j] != e) &&
                                      (str[j] != i).......//so on
```

However, in my opinion, if you change your logic to make use of a `switch` case, it'll be a better design.

Oh, and better to use `int main(void)`, that's recommended in standards.

Comment: I'd say you shouldn't create variables for char literals at all. You making your code dirty by creating variables, that used only once.

Comment: @EvgenBodunov Good point, but then again, that's a matter of personal choice, isn't it? There is nothing wrong it. So,.....(left to OP) :-)

Comment: You should probably also use `tolower()` so that the code works with capital letters too.

Comment: @Evgen Bodunov  I would not say that these variables make this simple code dirty.

Answer (score 0):

```
char str [100];
char *src;          // source position of copying characters
char *dst;          // destination position 

...........

gets(str); //gets user input
printf( "Input: %s\n" , str);

for( dst = src = str; *src; src++ )       // scan chars of the string
{
    if( *src != 'a' && *src != 'e' &&     // check if a vowel
        *src != 'i' && *src != 'o' && *src != 'u')
    {
        * dst ++ = * src;                 // no? copy it
    };
}
*dst = 0;  // ASCII NUL (zero) char to terminate the string

printf( "Result: %s\n" , str);
```

The `for` loop scans the whole string with a `src` pointer, starting from the beginning (`str`) till its end (a zero character, ASCII NUL, detected by a `*src` expression, equivalent to `*src != 0`).

Each character is tested and if it's not a vowel it gets copied to the `dest` position, which is then advanced by one (`* dst ++ = * src`). The `dest` variable is initially set to `str`, consequently all characters are copied one-by-one at the initial part of the string, except vowels. The last assignment (`*dst = 0`) terminates the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like `strchr`:

```
char vowels = "aeiou";
if (strchr(vowels, 'x'))
 // Then 'x' is a vowel.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going 1 char at a time anyhow to check if it is a vowel, so rather than using (insecure) `gets()` or using multiple arrays at all, you can just use `getchar()` and only add non-vowels to your array.  This simplifies the rest of the logic so you can just use pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h> //for puts and getchar
int main(void){
  char s[128], *sp = s, *end = sp + sizeof(s) - 1;
  puts("Please type in a string");
  while ((*sp=getchar())!='\n' && sp<end){
    switch(*sp|32){ // |32 will catch uppercase vowels too
    case 'a': case 'e' : case 'i' : case 'o' : case 'u' :
      continue; //*sp will be overwritten
    default :
      sp++;
    }
  }
  *sp=0;
  puts(s);
}
```

or using `strch()`

```
#include <stdio.h> //for puts and getchar
#include <string.h> //for strchr
int main(void){
  char s[128], *sp = s, *end = sp + sizeof(s) - 1;
  puts("Please type in a string");
  while ((*sp=getchar())!='\n' && sp<end)
    if (!strchr("aeiouAEIOU",*sp)) sp++;
  *sp=0;
  puts(s);
}
```